# I am trying to subset dataset with multiple conditions. It works when just the first condition is used, but not when I add the second condition

Tags: r, subset

Code to subset with first condition:

```r
 new <- subset(data, NDC == "L1000", select = GCharge:SelfPay)
 summary(new)

    GCharge         SelfPay     
 Min.   : 8513   Min.   : 3235  
 1st Qu.:34306   1st Qu.:13036  
 Median :48279   Median :18346  
 Mean   :42578   Mean   :16180  
 3rd Qu.:53918   3rd Qu.:20489  
 Max.   :56166   Max.   :21343
```

Code with subsetting on second condition:

```r
newmed <- subset(data, NDC == "L1000" & PROCEDURE == "%like%MED", 
                 select = GCharge:SelfPay)

 GCharge       SelfPay   
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA
```

I don't know why there are NAs with the second condition when there are no NAs in the "new" data subset?

Comment: have tagged with R as it looks a lot like R code to me, please change the tag if this isn't correct

Comment: It's easier to help if you [make this question reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by including a small representative dataset in a plain text format - for example the output from `dput(data)`, if that is not too large.

Comment: My guess is that you are trying to use `%like%` from DescTools and have the syntax wrong. You probably want `subset(data, NDC=="L1000" & PROCEDURE %like% "MED",select=GCharge:SelfPay)`

Comment: This is R code.    I tried the above answer and put in the code ...Procedure %like% "MED", select =GCharge:Selfpay and I got an error saying "could not find the function %like%".